# How do Apple II BASIC compilers compare?

Tags: apple-ii, compilers, applesoft-basic

Programs like [The Beagle Compiler](http://beagle.applearchives.com/the_software/vintage_beaglebros_software/the_beagle_compiler.html) allow AppleSoft BASIC or other Apple II BASIC variants to be compiled. How do the compilers compare in terms of compatibility with AppleSoft language features? Eg how often does unmodified BASIC code work with different compilers.

Comment: I bet most, if not all of them, just turn the program into a list of BASIC ROM calls, i.e. skip the tokenizing and interpreting stages. Beyond that some seem to offer some extensions the the (ahem) basic language.

Comment: If you are asking "how do they compare", at least list the compilers you are interested in.